# How to prevent a Javascript POST request triggering mod_security?

Tags: javascript, jquery, mod-security

I have a site which, using jQuery, uses Ajax to POST data to a PHP script to store in a database.

The POST data is a JSON object containing encoded polylines created by the Google Maps API.

Here is a basic sample object:

> [{"name":"Example Line","type":"LINE","data":[["#ff8200","2","3","0","0",36],{"\u0001":"lom-flying"},"\u0001New Point","gohwHqm{BhpCrG","\u0001New Point","}}cwH}d{BwImdE","\u0001New Point","uhdwHkjaC}_BwfF","\u0001New Point","sigwHcrhCd{C`{@"]}]

And this is an example of a POST request, with a couple of additional variables and the above object URI encoded:

> op=send&token=8685099e8880841638090ea9364184e05751c2b1-b0-1e7&data=LOMC%5B%7B%22name%22%3A%22Example+Line%22%2C%22type%22%3A%22LINE%22%2C%22data%22%3A%5B%5B%22%23ff8200%22%2C%222%22%2C%223%22%2C%220%22%2C%220%22%2C36%5D%2C%7B%22%5Cu0001%22%3A%22lom-flying%22%7D%2C%22%5Cu0001New+Point%22%2C%22gohwHqm%7BBhpCrG%22%2C%22%5Cu0001New+Point%22%2C%22%7D%7DcwH%7Dd%7BBwImdE%22%2C%22%5Cu0001New+Point%22%2C%22uhdwHkjaC%7D_BwfF%22%2C%22%5Cu0001New+Point%22%2C%22sigwHcrhCd%7BC%60%7B%40%22%5D%7D%5D

Originally I POSTed the data as a GPX file, and never had any problems.  But with more became very large, and so slow, quite quickly so I switched to this encoded format.  The data size is now much smaller (normally the encoded polylines would contain many points unlike the above examples).

But my web host uses mod_security on their servers, and I already ran into a problem with it refusing my post data.  The rule being triggered ("COMODO WAF: System Command Injection") seemed to be checking for a pipe symbol followed by alphanumeric characters.

Unfortunately the encoded Polylines may include this symbol, but my host simply whitelisted this particular rule for me which avoided the problem.

My script is now being refused again. Though I could go back to my host ask which rule was triggered and ask them to whitelist it, there is no way of knowing it will not keep asking.  (So I would like to recode to avoid the problem altogether.

So is there anything I can or should do to the way the data is POSTed to prevent it being blocked by mod_security?  Obviously this needs to be without significantly increasing the data size

Presumably it is specifically seeing the data as text as it would be impossible to avoid triggering sequences in a binary file and it must allow those.  Is there a way to flag or POST the data as binary in JQuery?

The PHP script, incidentally, simply checks the token is valid then escapes the data and places it in an SQL query.  No processing is done to the data on the server.

UPDATE:

Because Google uses ASCII characters 63 through 126 in its base64 encoding of polylines I have translated most of the non-alphabetic characters to digits, leaving only the underscore and tilde.  This has the dual benefit of avoiding any issues related to the bar symbol whilst also reducing the upload size by not having to URI encode any of the encoded polyline.

This has resolved the immediate issue I have been having with data being blocked by mod_security, although there is no guarantee that some rule may be triggered by a different unfortunate sequence in future.  So any suggestions would still be appreciated.

Comment: Unfortunately that's the downside of using a WAF. You need to monitor the log files to check for false positives. Though usually after a while you catch everything and it's rare to see new alerts.